# Illustrator: can't CTRL+S after opening and editing EPS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, eps

I have hundreds of EPS files and i need to find the most productive way to remove the backgrounds. The plan was to just load the files in illustrator, click background, delete, then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

However, when opened the files seem to have their titles renamed in Illustrator. For example, 'some_test_file.eps' gets renamed to 'some_test_file [Converted].eps'.

So when i hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, it opens the "Save As" dialog instead of just saving and overwriting the existing file.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences > General >` **Untick** "Append [Converted] Upon Opening Legacy Files"

Essentially, this option is provided so that files are not easily overwritten by a newer versions of Illustrator.

Newer EPS files may not adhere to previous EPS standards. For example, for many, many years Illustrator 8 was the preferred format for EPS files from Illustrator. And in some cases, it is still preferred to save EPS files to AI8 EPS format.

This preference item merely allows the user to be *aware* of when they are overwriting old file formats.